# How can I find UIElement in WPF?

Tags: wpf

How can I find first element (Grid element) in every Window ?
I need to get window children.But I dont want to use "VisualStateHelper".
Thanks your help.

Comment: For the first element, all you do is casting the `Content` property. Something like `var grid = yourWindow.Content as Grid;`

Comment: Do you mean `LogicalTreeHelper`?

Comment: Sorry I've written wrong. You are right "VisualTreeHelper"

Comment: Thanks for help. I have tried this code: "var grid = yourWindow.Content as Grid;" it works. Thanks a lot @King King.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will do it all statically. You can call it from anywhere.

```
    using System.Windows;

    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the child <see cref="System.Windows.Grid"/> instances of all windows that have them as the first child.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An enumerable of tuples pairing the window instance with the child grid.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<Window, Grid>> GetAllGrids()
    {
        foreach (var window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            Grid grid = this.Content as Grid; //grid will be null if the first child is not a Grid
            if (grid != null)
            {
                yield return Tuple.Create(window, grid);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this.Content should do the trick

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Grid grid = this.Content as Grid; //grid will be null if the first child is not a Grid
    if(grid != null)
    {
         //do the work you want to do
    }
}
```